# Data about administrative subdivisions capital cities

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries, africa

I am looking for data about **second or third rank administrative capitals** in **every African country** (the administrative centre of a country territorial subdivision), but I can't find anything close to what I'm looking for.

So far, I found data on administrative boundaries ([GADM](http://www.gadm.org/version2), [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/), [UN SALB Project](http://www.unsalb.org/), [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)) and about cities ([Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/), [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/)), but nothing that specifically links an administrative subdivision to its administrative capital.

Although Geonames is supposed to provide that kind of information, I briefly checked and found that the data is of very poor quality.

Comment: Not sure there are the informations you need but have a look at http://geonames.nga.mil/gns/html/namefiles.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check out http://www.mapmakerdata.co.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/library/stacks/Africa/index.htm might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked it out, unfortunately there seems to be only polygon features. I couldn't find any data containing cities.

Answer (score 0):

in case you are still searching, there is https://data.humdata.org which is a big database regularly updated. Maybe something on it can help you.